# What does C++ mean by "expression must have pointer-to-object type" and "subscript requires array or pointer type"?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I began writing a function that would take a size x size two-dimensional vector, and return a copy of what it looks like when it has been rotated 90 degrees clockwise. I got here:

```
std::vector<int> rotate90(std::vector<int> orig, int size) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> r;
    r.resize(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       r[i].resize(size);
       for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          r[i][j] = orig[size - j - 1][i];
       }
    }
}
```

However, it says that there's a problem with the last line: "expression must have pointer-to-object type" and "subscript requires array or pointer type". I'm pretty new to using C++, so I looked up some things about using pointers with vectors, but I'm still not sure how to implement them in a way that'll work here.

Comment: It might not be the the clearest or most interesting question ever. But still, closing off-topic feels wrong to me. OP is confused about what his function receives. We could clarify it. Or, at the very close it duplicate, or something, not OT.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `orig` is not a 2D vector.

```
std::vector<int> orig
```

is a 1D vector, so

```
orig[size - j - 1][i]
```

doesn't compile.